# Adding UITableViewCell to UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that is set to Static and contains 7 cells .  Each cell has a Label to the left and a TextField to the right. I have an event that fires every time the contents of the TextField change.

Every time the event is triggered, it calls a method that validates the input of the text field. If the contents fail my validation, then I want a new cell to appear below the current cell (with the text field being edited by the user) that indicates what exactly is wrong with their input.

Doing so, produces this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to add a static cell underneath the current cell having its UITextLabel being edited. Can someone help or provide an example?

I'm assuming that I need to update 'numberOfRowsInSection' somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: A `static` tableView is `static` therefore you can not change the number of rows etc. You'll have to implement this dynamically using the standard `UITableView(Delegate | DataSource)` methods

Comment: what do you mean by static? Do you mean it contains static content or it is declared as static?
Also how do you try to update the contents? The exception description states that you tried to insert something. Could you share some more code?

Comment: The OP must be using a static tableView from a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

What paul i saying that you need to go to your storyboard and make the table dynamic. By the way once you do that you cannot just drag and drop UITextlabels on it. You will have to add them in programmatically

[image]

Since you maybe new to iOS, I would highly suggest that you google UITableView tutorials and look at sample code, try them out.

Answer (score 0):

This is [UITableView tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/)

add UITableViewDelegate | UITableViewDataSource in interface